# In jquery name='other' then jquery but i have select name. how to get select option name in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In jquery name='other' then jquery but i have select name. how to get select option value & select value name?

Please help.....

```
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield(name){
  if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('others').innerHTML='<input type="text" name='this.name' />';
  else document.getElementById('others').innerHTML='';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="abc[]" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
<option value="Plane">Plane</option>
<option value="Train">Train</option>
<option value="Own Vehicle">Own Vehicle</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="others"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Initial observation: there's no jQuery in your code.

Comment: you try using jquery or javascript clear it?